# Change color of image caption based on image least dominent color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try to figure out a way by which i can change image caption color to other color if image color where image caption is displayed is same.

i show image caption at bottom left of the image & it is possible that image color & caption color cant be same making caption reading difficult.

I found  following link to change the background color based on more dominent color of the image.

https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js

I tried to implement same Text but it is not working... I have also set of a fiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/4do2n5qt/1/

CODE:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8378/8559402848_9fcd90d20b_b.jpg" data-adaptive-background='1'/>
        <div class="caption">Caption here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.arup.com/~/media/Images/Projects/O/Oresund_Link/Gallery/Images/Oresund2_900x600.ashx?mh=800&mw=1000" data-adaptive-background='1'/>
        <div class="caption">Caption here</div>
    </div>
        <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.argesit.net/plantillas/fx-template/images/Galeria/1small9-900x600.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">Caption here</div>
    </div>
        <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.colouration.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Gap-03-900-X-600-pixels.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">Caption here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example caption is readable but in actual scenario some images have white background making image caption almost invisible.

Comment: Practically this may be possible but for now i thought of using `text-shawdow` css property `text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;` this now has made caption more visible http://jsfiddle.net/4do2n5qt/2/

Comment: Not a direct answer, but there's another plugin you might find use of - https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check - changes color of an element depending on brightness of background.

Comment: You're using images from other domains - I imagine this will have an impact on getting the image data needed in the script. Try hosting them locally?

Comment: I use dummy image only for this purpose and i am using also window.load query function so that i can perform all calculation after image is downloaded

Comment: Ok well the fiddle won't work.  Additionally you aren't including `data-adaptive-background='1'` on all the images.  Also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Any caption should have a surrounding "box" property (or "block-level" property in CSS-speak).  You can always color that box something different than the caption.  Then it won't matter what color the image has, upon which you are displaying the boxed caption.

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim, I usually do this, but what is client request for what i have mentioned in the question. Practically it possible but wont be always perfect as image can have different level of colors at pixel level and with CSS font we can only specify 1 type of color for whole font.